# meteorpad - For how long sources are stored?

Tags: meteor

Q1: I would like to know for how long time a project (url/id) is stable and available on meteorpad.

I would like to create running test pads which can be stored as examples or details for descriptions in issue trackers and knowledge boards like GitHub or MeteorForum.

So if I save a link to the meteorpad project in a post, is this safe that also in next future someone can have a look at this? This would be often much better than just to copy parts of the sources to your own entries.

Q2: Is there a difference (overall pad life time) if you create the pad as a registered user or not?

Thanks for feedback
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Have found the info about the MeteorPad launch on this page : https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/09/01/meteorpad-meteor-code-playground

Have twitted the created, Mike Risse with your question. I'll let you know if he replies. Or you can check yourself my tweet here : https://twitter.com/geniium/status/593841039783366657

Cheers!